# Should [tag:jello] be a synonym of [tag:gelatin]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I don't have enough rep to directly suggest a synonym, but I have just observed (via a question that was closely related to one I asked a while back) that there are separate [jello](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jello) (9 questions) and [gelatin](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gelatin) (48 questions) tags, with no overlap. I believe that Jell-O is just a brand name for gelatin products, so is there any reason why it should not be a synonym of [gelatin](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gelatin)?

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, I can't think of any occasion where "gelatin" won't cover "jello".

Synonym created.